# Django: how to add constraints on the foreign key dashboard

Tags: django, post, foreign-keys, django-generic-views

I have the model below:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class AccountCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
       return Account.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

I want to create an account of which the owner is the same as the request.user. But when I tried to create a new account, the dashboard displayed all the users. How to make the choices only be the request.user?

As it is shown in the image with the red circles below, the owner could be wz, but I only want it to be victor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one choice, why are you making this a field on the form in the first place? If you remove the owner field from the form, and automatically set the user as the owner in the view, wouldn't that be easier for the user, and less work for you? Furthermore, if the whole form is just that one question (and if this question has only one possible answer), wouldn't it be easier to process object creation in the view, when a button is pressed or something?